# How to generate null for nullable types with FsCheck?

Tags: c#, fscheck

I have this generator that seems to work, but when I check the values generated, it never picks the null value. How does one write generator that will pick null value. This code never picks null value for "end" date.

```
public static Gen<DateTime?> NullableDateTimeGen()
    {
        var list = new List<DateTime?>();

        if (list.Any() == false)
        {
            var endDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);
            var startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);

            list.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + endDate.Subtract(startDate).Days)
                .Select(offset => startDate.AddDays(offset))
                .Cast<DateTime?>()
                .ToList());

            list.Add(null);
            list.Insert(0, null);
        }

        return from i in Gen.Choose(0, list.Count - 1)
               select list[i];
    }

    public static Arbitrary<Tuple<DateRange, DateTime>> TestTuple()
    {
        return (from s in NullableDateTimeGen().Where(x => x != null)
                from e in NullableDateTimeGen()
                from p in NullableDateTimeGen().Where(x => x != null)
                where s <= e
                select new Tuple<DateRange, DateTime>(new DateRange(s.Value, e), p.Value))
                .ToArbitrary();
    }
```

Comment: What exactly does not pick null values? NullableDateTimeGen or TestTuple function?

Comment: @Evk: TestTuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not related to FsCheck and is in this statement:

```
from s in NullableDateTimeGen().Where(x => x != null)
            from e in NullableDateTimeGen()
            from p in NullableDateTimeGen().Where(x => x != null)
            where s <= e
            select new Tuple<DateRange, DateTime>(new DateRange(s.Value, e), p.Value))
```

Note that you filter nulls from `s` and `p`, so they are never null. The only thing that can be null if `e`. However, you do

```
where s <= e
```

This comparision can never be true if `e` is null, because anything compared with null is always false. So you filter out null values for `e` also.

To fix just replace that condition with whatever makes sense for your scenario, like

```
where e == null || s <= e
```